# How to refer objects on the stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

I have an object created visually. How should I refer to it from classes of other objects? `MovieClip(this.root).someObj` or `stage.someObj` or `MovieClip(this.root).stage.someObj`? And moreover, if I want to see which frame is current on the main timeline, why I cannot just check `stage.currentFrame`? Why there is no such property of the stage, `currentFrame`? It has timeline, right?

Comment: I think `root` refers to the main timeline. Have you tried `root.currentFrame`? Regarding the object that gets created "visually" - does that mean the user draws onto a Shape or Sprite object?  In that case, whatever class you are using to handle their drawing input should also manage the reference to the final drawing, and then make that available to other classes through an event like "drawing_finished" or by a property like `drawingController.drawings //returns Array` or something.  To really address your question though, we'll probably need more details.

Comment: i mean visually created MovieClip that is dragged to the stage.

Comment: at the runtime or in e.g. flash ide?

Comment: if you have MovieCliip named abc on the stage, than you can directly access it using MovieClip(root).abc.x = 65;

Comment: Why are you not posting these as answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

root is the timeline, so MovieClip(root).someObj would do it. This should be pretty trivial to test for yourself :)